# Positioning the control buttons on the sides of the div element

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I use the OwlCarousel2 plugin in my project. How do I better position the navigation buttons on the sides of the div element (pagination points).

[image as i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fefvP.png)

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
<div class="owl-stage-outer">
    <div class="owl-stage">
        <div class="owl-item">...</div>
        <div class="owl-item">...</div>
        <div class="owl-item">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-nav">
    <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
    <div class="owl-next">next</div>
</div>
<div class="owl-dots">
    <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
    <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
    <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can write css rules to the owl-prev and owl-next css classes.

Comment: I know it. But how to position relative to dotsClass